# 「git push -u origin master」の結果できた「Default branch」「Your branches」「Active branches」について

Tags: git, github

初めてのコミットを「Git Bash」で「git push -u origin master」したら、「Default branch」ではなく「Your branches」と「Active branches」へアップロードされました。

```
$ git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

nothing to commit, working tree clean


$ git remote -v
origin  git@github.com:hoge/xx.git (fetch)
origin  git@github.com:hoge/xx.git (push)
```

Q1.「Your branches」が作成されたのは、「git push -u origin main」ではなく「git push -u origin master」としたためですか？

Q2.「Active branches」というのは、ここへアップロードされているわけではない？
3 か月以内の履歴を表示しているだけですか？

Comment: GitHub 上での "All branches" の画面を含めてみてください。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GitHub ではリポジトリごとに Default Branch を設定できるので、必要なら master に変更することももちろん可能です。

**設定画面の表示例:**

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

"Your Branches" と "Active branches" はそれぞれフィルタの結果なので、「ここにアップロードされた」という表現は適切ではない気がします。

- Your Branches ... 他から Fork したリポジトリで、自分が追加したブランチが表示される
- Active Branches ... 過去3ヶ月以内にコミットが追加されたブランチが表示される

Comment: 「Active branches」の件はこの回答で分かりました。